# can't draw item after I get it from queue

Tags: c++, opengl

I've got three `CustomPixel` objects - when I draw it directly in draw function `draw` - it works normal.

But when I put them into `queue` and draw them one after another with `while` loop - there are not any rectangles on the screen.

Here is my code

```
#include <gl\glew.h>
#include <gl\freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "OpenGL.h"
#include "Constants.h"
#include "Geometrics.h"
#include <queue>


std::queue<CustomPixel*> queue;
CustomPixel *pixel1 = new CustomPixel(0.0, 250.0, 100.0);
CustomPixel *pixel2 = new CustomPixel(101.0, 250.0, 100.0);
CustomPixel *pixel3 = new CustomPixel(202.0, 250.0, 100.0);

void draw() {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   

glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    pixel1->drawRectangle(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); //it works!
    if (!queue.empty()) {
        while(!queue.empty()) {
            CustomPixel *item = queue.front();
            //doesn't work -> but
            //in debugger it enters this method with correct  CustomPixel 
            //attributes(x1, x2...etc)
            item->drawRectangle(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); 
            queue.pop();
        }
    }
glEnd();

glFlush();
};

int main(int iArgc, char** cppArgv) {

//console for debug

OpenGL *opengl = new OpenGL(iArgc, cppArgv);
opengl->setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
opengl->setWindowPosition(200, 200);
opengl->create();

//after OpenGL object created -> fill the queue with objects and the draw it
queue.push(pixel1);
queue.push(pixel2);
queue.push(pixel3);

opengl->run(draw);//<- can be any draw function


//clean all garbage
delete pixel1;
delete pixel2;
delete pixel3;

delete opengl;

return 0;
}
```

P.S it has been a long time since I used c++. Maybe I forgot something?

Here drawRectangle method

```
void CustomPixel::drawRectangle(float r, float g, float b) {
glColor3f(r, g, b);
CustomLine::drawLine(this->x1, this->y1, this->x1, this->y2);
CustomLine::drawLine(this->x1, this->y1, this->x2, this->y1);
CustomLine::drawLine(this->x2, this->y1, this->x2, this->y2);
CustomLine::drawLine(this->x2, this->y2, this->x1, this->y2);
};
```

and drawLine

```
void CustomLine::drawLine(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
float dx = (x2 - x1) / STEP;
float dy = (y2 - y1) / STEP;
float vX = x1 / WIDTH;
float vY = y1 / HEIGHT;

for(int i = 0; i < STEP; i++) {
    glVertex2f(vX + dx * i / WIDTH, vY + dy * i / HEIGHT);
}
};
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your use of std::queue here. (As you have noticed in your comment). Is it possible that the gl*() calls (or are they macros?) have to be called in the same scope as drawRectangle()?

Comment: Where is `drawRectangle (...)`'s implementation? There are a lot of OpenGL operations that are invalid between `glBegin` and `glEnd`, if you trigger even just 1 invalid operation at the end of `drawRectangle (...)` then all subsequent calls to `drawRectangle (...)` in your begin/end block will have undefined results.

Comment: It looks like it works the first time. Then everything is popped off the list and `draw()` is called repeatedly. So the first render is `glClear`ed and nothing more gets rendered.

Comment: Yes! I should not have used method `queue.pop()` in `draw` method.